# Dotnet Core 7.0 Console Application Size

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have the following dotnet core 7.0 console application code. As you can see the code is very small and I have a version of this code written in straight C. I'd like to move away from the C code and use the C# code, however the file size goes for 45k to 11Mb. I'm not quite sure why, but is there anyway I can shrink this code .exe file? I'm target output is for windows x64. It only needs to run on windows.

```
using System.Net;

namespace v4tov6
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static Dictionary<string, string> v4tov6replacementDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "192.168.56.112/28","1111:aa:bb:cc:210:0:0:112"},
            { "192.168.56.48/28","1111:aa:bb:cc:130:56:0:0"},
        };

        public static bool valid_ip(string address)
        {
            try
            {
                IPAddress test = IPAddress.Parse(address.Trim());
                return true;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static uint ip_cidrtouintmask(byte CIDR)
        {
            return 0xFFFFFFFF << (32 - CIDR);
        }

        public static uint ip_iptouint(string ip)
        {
            IPAddress i = IPAddress.Parse(ip.Trim());
            byte[] ipByteArray = i.GetAddressBytes();

            uint ipUint = (uint)ipByteArray[0] << 24;
            ipUint += (uint)ipByteArray[1] << 16;
            ipUint += (uint)ipByteArray[2] << 8;
            ipUint += (uint)ipByteArray[3];

            return ipUint;
        }

        public static uint ip_networkAddress(uint Network, uint Subnet)
        {
            return (Subnet & Network);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Usage: '{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName} <ip4 address>");
                return;
            }

            string v4addressAsString = args[0];
            if (!valid_ip(v4addressAsString))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{v4addressAsString} is not a valid IPv4 address");
                return;
            }

            uint v4addressToConvert = ip_iptouint(v4addressAsString);

            foreach (var v4Address in v4tov6replacementDictionary)
            {
                uint v4replacementNetwork = ip_iptouint(v4Address.Key.Split("/")[0]);
                uint v4replacementMask = ip_cidrtouintmask(byte.Parse(v4Address.Key.Split("/")[1]));
                if (ip_networkAddress(v4addressToConvert, v4replacementMask) == v4replacementNetwork)
                {
                    string ipv6_string = v4Address.Value;

                    int hextet8Pos = ipv6_string.LastIndexOf(':');
                    uint hextet8 = uint.Parse(ipv6_string.Substring(hextet8Pos + 1));

                    int hextet7Pos = ipv6_string.LastIndexOf(":", hextet8Pos - 1);
                    uint hextet7 = uint.Parse(ipv6_string.Substring(hextet7Pos + 1, (hextet8Pos - hextet7Pos - 1)));

                    int hextet6Pos = ipv6_string.LastIndexOf(":", hextet7Pos - 1);
                    uint hextet6 = uint.Parse(ipv6_string.Substring(hextet6Pos + 1, (hextet7Pos - hextet6Pos - 1)));

                    uint offset = v4addressToConvert - v4replacementNetwork;
                    hextet6 += offset >> 8;
                    hextet8 += offset % 256;

                    ipv6_string = ipv6_string.Remove(hextet6Pos + 1) + $"{hextet6}:{hextet7}:{hextet8}";
                    Console.WriteLine($"{v4addressAsString}\t\t{ipv6_string}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Project File:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <PublishAot>true</PublishAot>
    <StripSymbols>true</StripSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Publish Profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\net7.0\publish\win-x64\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishSingleFile>false</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: How do you want to distribute it? Standalone? Framework-dependend (i.e. requires runtime installed)? Is it even a problem? 11 Mb not that big.

Comment: AOT compilation may be one option, see also the tab on optimization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net7

Comment: right now we use a C program to generate the exe file and it is a single .exe file. I would like to keep the same method as this program I'm on doesn't like change.

Comment: I tested, the compiled result is ~180Kb... can you show the csproj?

Comment: @KevinC AOT got the file down from 11mb to 3mb. This is great. The C file was about 45k. I don't know if its realistic to think I could get to 1mb or less?

Comment: i created a blank console project just to see. Even with a blank one saying "hello world" it is 11mb. Enable AOT and you get it to right at 3mb. Seems like a big program for "hello world"?

Comment: "Even with a blank one saying "hello world" it is 11mb" - *if* you make it self-contained. That's not what happens out of the box though. Just "dotnet new console" followed by "dotnet build" with no other changes does *not* produce an 11MB executable.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why the output file is over 11MB is that you're using the "SelfContained" option. Using this option causes the resulting program to contain the .NET runtime and required libraries. This means that there will be no need to install additional dependencies such as .NET Runtime separately on the system. The advantage is that it will be easier to run, but the drawback is that it is much heavier. An analogous program compiled with the "FrameworkDependent" option would weigh about 150KB. Unfortunately, .NET programs require a dedicated runtime to operate - unlike programs written in C.